# Regexing fields in java

Tags: java, regex

Im currently using this to make a guessing field not accept numbers. Is there anyway i can restructure this so i can make the field not accepting numbers AND special characters such as #@^<>.

```
private static final String REMOVE_REGEX = "\\d";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all of those characters to a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

```
private static final String REMOVE_REGEX = "[\\d#@^<>]";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^\\d#@^<>.]+$
```

This will match anything except numbers and special characters as in your list.

If you want to do inverse (i.e. match numbers OR special characters) then remove first negation from regex i.e.

```
^[\\d#@^<>.]+$
```